# Ordenar una lista de forma ascendente en JavaScript de forma recursiva y en el paradigma funcional

Tags: javascript

Bunas buenas, necesito ordenar una lista de forma recursiva pero no puedo usar bucles como for, do o do while, tampoco declarar variables y todo lo que falte al paradigma funcional. He intentado hacerlo pero solo lo logro declarando variables, utilize el metodo burbuja...

```
console.log(sort([3,4,4,1,2,5]))
   function sort(list){
  return sort1(list, list.length)
    }

   function sort1(list, iter){
   if(iter == 0){
     return list;
      }
     list = sortasc(list, 0)
     return sort1(list, iter - 1 )
      }
      function sortasc(list, index){
      if(index == list.length){
      return list; 
      }         
      if(list[index] > list[index + 1]){

      let temp = list[index];
      list[index] = list[index +1];
      list[index + 1] = temp
       }
       if(index != list.length){
       return sortasc(list, index + 1) 
        }
        }
```